# What are some advanced techniques for matching sequences to a formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

I have the following sequence:

$$\lbrace a_n\rbrace=\lbrace 10,48,126,254,438,690,1023,1451,1989...\rbrace$$

which I am trying to match a function to.

I understand I can use arithmetic progression to find a polynomial:

$$ \begin {array} {l l l l l l} 10&48&126&254&438&690&1023&1451&1989\\38&78&128&184&252&333&428&538\\40&50&56&68&81&95&110\\10&6&12&13&14&15\\-4&6&1&1&1  \end {array}$$

because a pattern does emerge for $n > 2 $. I can then derive a formula using typical methods, and get:

$$ a(n)= \frac{n^4 + 30n^3 + 215n^2 + 282n - 648}{24} $$

This function works for all $n > 2 $, but gives $a(1) = -5$ and $a(2) = 43$ (instead of $10$ and $48$ respectively).

Is there any advanced formula formulation technique that would allow me to make the formula work for all n, not just $n > 2 $? I figure the $-4$ and $6$ differences in the arithmetic progression method could be a clue, but I'm not sure what to do with it. I am unable to find such information online.

(I'm looking for a method that would work generally, rather than a quick fix for this specific sequence.)

Comment: [polynomial interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner If I understood correctly, polynomial interpolation just hits the points and everything else is unknown. Meaning, if the sequence continues, the polynomial interpolation has no guarantee to keep matching it, whereas the function I came up with fits for all n except 1 and 2. Is my understanding of polynomial interpolation incorrect?

Comment: Just confirmed it myself, it doesn't match it perfectly. If I use polynomial interpolation with the first 9 terms I described above, the 10th is off by 20 or so. So I am looking for a different solution.

Comment: You're saying the degree-$4$ polynomial you have works for all $n>2$ and you want to adjust it to work for $n \leq 2$?  Why not just define a piecewise function? The polynomial you gave is uniquely determined because it agrees on all but finitely many points. So **no** other polynomial will fit on more than finitely many points.

Comment: @JairTaylor I considered that, but the issue is that there are similar polynomials I am constructing that only start working at, for example, $n=5$. Then defining the correct solution in a piecewise function becomes much less elegant. Can you explain the uniquely determined part? Do you mean there is no solution, or what?

Comment: You have a polynomial $p(n)$ so that $p(n) = a_n$ for all $n > 2$.  If there is another function $q(n)$ so that $q(n) = a_n$ for all $n$, then $p(n)$ and $q(n)$ agree on infinitely many points and so must be equal.  But then $p(1) = q(1) \neq a_1$, a contradiction.  So there can be no polynomial solution.

Comment: So I'd just give the polynomial you know is correct for $n>k$ and then describe the $n\leq k$ case separately.  Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Okay, thanks, that answers it. If you want to post that as an answer so I can mark it as the solution, feel free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a polynomial $p(n)$ so that $p(n) = a_n$ for all $n > 2$. If there is another polynomial $q(n)$ so that $q(n) = a_n$ for all $n$, then $p(n)$ and $q(n)$ agree on infinitely many points and so must be equal. But then $p(1) = q(1) = a_1$, a contradiction since the formula fails for $n=1$. So there can be no polynomial solution. I would just write it as a piecewise function - that is as simple as you will be able to get.

Often, the best solution to fit a formula to a sequence is to look it up in [OEIS](http://oeis.org). Your sequence doesn't seem to be there, so if you think it is particularly interesting mathematically you may consider submitting it.  You could also use the [superseeker](http://oeis.org/wiki/Email_Servers_and_Superseeker) to try harder to find a fit.